# How to port foward from a static ip to a nat through another VM in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, iptables

Okay,
I have two virtual machines (RedHat 5.0, and Kali) on a Windows 7 host. My Windows host has internet, however my issue is getting RedHat to see the web being locked down to a single address `192.168.56.103`, *it cannot be changed*

Kali can 'see' the RedHat and vice versa. I was wondering if there is a way of port forwarding everything out of Redhat through Kali onto the web.

The interfaces in Kali are:
`eth0` at `10.0.2.15`
`eth1` at `192.168.56.100`

RedHat is locked down to `eth0 192.168.56.103`

I have read the man page for `iptables` and followed some guides on how to portforward but to no avail.

commands I have tried on Kali:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.15:80`
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.2.15 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.56.103`

I have tried many of the settings using the GUI in virtualbox for port forwarding also to no avail.

If some could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

[pic of GUI settings in Kali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4vZf.png)

EDIT:
Let me clarify,
In Virtual Box the interface `eth0` on RedHat is **internal**
the interface for Kali is `eth0` is NAT and `eth1` is internal
Having a Bridged connection for RedHat is also not working because the Dynamic Host Protocol daemon has been shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have activated the `Host only network` configuration for RedHat. You have two options:

1. keep it as it is, issue this command on the RedHat VM

   ```
   sudo ip route add default via 192.168.56.1
   ```

   and then activate **ICS** (Internet Connection Sharing) on Windows 7.
2. Change the network configuration of the RedHat VM by choosing the option `Bridged Adapter`, and then under `Name` choose the current interface with which your Windows machine is connected to the Internet (wifi or Ethernet, whichever). Then your RedHat VM will automatically get an IP address on your LAN, and will be able to navigate freely.

   If you wish to retain the connection with the Kali machine, do **not** erase the current configuration, just aa the new Bridged Adapter to the adapter you already have.